# Get raw transaction from transaction Id using web3js or something similar in nodejs

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

So i will give an example let's say i have the transaction id https://etherscan.io/tx/0xafef64d0d03db9f13c6c3f8aec5902167ea680bd0ffa0268d89a426d624b2ae1

In etherscan i can use their menu to see the raw transaction which will be

> 0xf8a915850516aab3ad82be7c947d1afa7b718fb893db30a3abc0cfc608aacfebb080b844095ea7b300000000000000000000000022b1cbb8d98a01a3b71d034bb899775a76eb1cc2ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff26a003daa35e6aa4a7cd439133411a390ff0796420d5cb39e9e276db75b01218ed41a028605f36c601527bd435b36da5403ee972fc2fb2c8f70959199bcdba0d0e8c77

I can't get this with etherscan api or geth rpc , i have found eth_getRawTransaction but it give just 0x for transfer transaction
is there anyway i can find the raw transaction using nodejs code

thank you

Answer (score 0):

use a provider like alchemy or smth, then you can get the decoded transaction object;

```
let txn = await alchemy.core.getTransaction(log.transactionHash);
console.log(txn);
```

...and you can later decode specific parts of the tx; just look at the `console.log()` and find what you're looking for.

Comment: yeah this give only the transaction object , i need a way to parse that to a raw transaction , some informations are missing for getTransaction response